# Controller load order in AngularJS when loading from bookmark

Tags: angularjs

In my HomeController I load data from a Web API service and only navigate to the default state of the application (I'm using ui-router) once that data has been loaded. I store the data (user details, settings, etc) in a CacheService that gets injected into any other controllers that need to access to it - which means I only need to load it once.

So once the data has been loaded I then navigate to the default state of the application using $state.go('/diary'), and the DiaryController gets access to the data in the CacheService as expected.

However if a user types in the url directly into the browser (e.g. http://www.somedomain.com/diary), then the DiaryController code executes first - which is bad because that the data has not been loaded into the CacheService yet by the HomeController.

My question is how do I force AngularJS to always run the HomeController before any other controllers in this scenario?

Comment: Why do you have the logic in the home controller and not a your cacheservice, then it would not matter which controller is called first?

Comment: It's a reasonably large app so the settings will be shared with a number of controllers, many of which can be active at once as I'm using nested views. I want to be able to load the data first, and then run the application. Let me know if I'm approaching things here from the wrong angle...

Comment: @AdamValipied as I said I would use a service since they are singletons they are the ideal place for id. And using promises you can make sure that you don't load the data twice but are still able to handle multiple clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Service instead of a controller. Something along these lines

```
ng.factory ("dataService", function ($http, $q) {

  var infoDeferred = $q.defer();
  var infoPromise = infoDeferred.promise;

  // eagerly load the data
  $http.get("", {cache: true}).then(function (d) {
     infoDeferred.resolve(d)
  });

  return {
    // always return same promise
    getInfo: function () {return infoPromise;}
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. I know how to do all of that, but it's appreciated - although I had not seen the cache: true setting before. I'm not sure that will work as there are 3 nested controllers that need the data in the cache service immediately once the site loads (the diary, heading bar, and side menu). I would imagine that would start three different $http calls as the resolves would all be run at the same time. It would be perfect if they were guaranteed to execute at different times. Am I right in thinking this?

Comment: Is there a way I can stop AngularJS from automatically routing to the state defined in the URL?

Comment: @AdamValpied this controller will only do one call even without the `cache: true`, the trick is the promise. Since all Controllers get the same promise they don't actually trigger another http call and as you can see the service does not wait for a getInfo call but eagerly load the data.

Comment: Ah yes sorry - because you are returning the promise rather than the data itself. Sorry - not with it at all last night. Working perfectly now. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You would have to look at `resolve` in `ui-router`. These are object maps that get resolved before the controllers are initiated and are injected into the controller. Since most probably you are loading data asynchronously from server, you would have to use resolves functions that return promise.

The controllers would get created only when the promise is resolved. See documentation of `resolve` on the wiki https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Comment: I did look into that but I couldn't see how I would only load the data once - many controllers will be accessing this data - possibly at the same time. Are you saying that you can use a singleton instance of a service in the resolve and return either the data from the server, or a cached version of it?

Comment: If you are using a cache service. You can create a `load` method on the cache service that returns a promise, it should load all remote data and finally resolve the promise on successful completion. I am not sure of your exact scenario to guide you further.